# Windows Phone 7 XNA game quits on load, no error messages

Tags: windows-phone-7, xna, quit

I'm trying to get a Windows Phone 7 XNA game to run in the emulator, however it simply quits after calling the Game.Initialize function. The only output it gives is:

> A first chance exception of type
>   'System.NotSupportedException'
>   occurred in
>   Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.dll
>   'taskhost.exe' (Managed): Loaded
>   'Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices.dll'
>   A first chance exception of type
>   'System.Threading.ThreadAbortException'
>   occurred in
>   Microsoft.Xna.Framework.dll

No idea why, the same program runs fine when running for Windows desktop.

OK upon further investigation I've found that the error occurs because I'm initailizing spritebatch in Game.Initialize:

```
        base.Initialize();
        if (spriteBatch == null)
        {
            spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);
        }
```

If I remove spriteBach = new ... it runs fine, however when I initialize it the update/draw functions the game WILL just exit...

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. The game exits gracefully when you create the spritebatch in update or draw? Or does it throw an exception at etc?

Comment: The exceptions are thrown after the update/draw calls have finished executing, then I get the exceptions quoted in my post after which the game just exits. No errors or warnings and I can't 'catch' the exception because it's happening behind the scene...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I found out what the problem was. I was basically trying to draw a non power of 2 texture while using texture wrapping which the reach API of Windows Phone 7 does not like. I'm not sure why I didn't get an exception thrown for this (last time I did something like this I actually got an exception thrown).

I should have been more clear in my question, when I didn't initialize spritebatch I was also skeeping draw calls too.

At any rate that was the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use the `GraphicsDevice` (like, for example, by having `SpriteBatch` create the various graphics device resources it requires) until `LoadContent` is called, as the graphics device is not ready until then.

See [`Game.GraphicsDevice` on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.game.graphicsdevice.aspx):

> Do not access this property until LoadContent is called.

Comment: that was my initial suspision too (even though it was working before when it was in Initailize). When I moved it to LoadContent() it still didn't work, when I moved it to run *after* loadcontent function had finished executing it still didn't work with the exact same error..